# compare the linear equation systems Ax=y and BCx=y with A=BC.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let for example $A$ be a $4\times 4$-matrix over a field k, such that A is a product of two matrices, $A=BC$, with B is a $4\times 3$-matrix and C is a $3\times 4$-matrix. I will compare the properties of the matrices in the linear equation systems 
$Ax=y$ (1) and 
$BCx=y$ (2) in case of: 1. (1) and (2) have an unique solution, 2. (1) and (2) have infinitily many solutions and 3. (1) and (2) have no solution. What can I say about injectivity/surjectivity of A, B and C? 
$x\in k^{4\times 1}$ and $x\in y^{4\times 1}$.
 
If A is invertible, what can I say about B and C for example, one has to respresent a surjective linear map, this means the rank of one of these matrices should be full and the other matrix has kernel zero, or must both be invertible? Could you explain me, which matrix has full rank and which has kernel zero? 
 If in (1) A is invertible, (1) and (2) have unique solutions.
What can I say if (1) and (2) has infinity many solutions and no solution about the matrices A, B and C?

Comment: You have $K^4\to K^3 \to K^4, x\to Ax=BCx.$ Can $B$ be surjective?

Comment: I would say no. B represents a linear map $f:k^3\to k^4$ and the  dimension of the image of f could not be greater than 3, is this correct?

Comment: In a similar way $C$ is not injective. Thus, $A$ can't be invertible.

Comment: ah okay, then Ax=y has never an unique solution, right? so (1) and (2) have no solution or infinitely many solutions. C can be surjective, in this case (1) and (2) have infinitely many solutions I would say. If C is not surjective, what can I say in this case?

Comment: Well, if $K$ is finite for example, you can't have infinitely many solutions.

Comment: yes, you are right. Can I say something else about the number of solutions of the linear equation systems?

Comment: and is A only invertible if B and C are invertible?

Comment: You can say that the system has no unique solution. Note that $B$ is not invertible (not surjective) nor $C$ is invertible (not injective).